# Reference for Indian ETA application

Tags: india, e-visas

We are planning to get an E-visa for India but it asks for a reference. I've heard occasionally that you can just put in the hotel where you staying but this application asks specifically for a name.

We reached out to a few hotels and ask if they can supply a name but so far no reply.

What's the best practice here?

[image]

Comment: Do you know an individual person in India who might vouch for you?

Comment: No I don't. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been granted Indian visas (both paper and electronic) by putting the name of a hotel in there, without asking permission or trying to figure out an individual's name in advance:

[image: snap of an Indian visa application]

There are no guarantees you will see the same results, of course, but I'm pretty sure the hotel was never called in my cases.

If your application is otherwise "problematic" (i.e., you have a connection to Pakistan or are from a country whose citizens often have immigration troubles in India), I guess you could try to figure out how to take extra precautions, but it's probably not worth worrying about it too much otherwise.

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly what I was looking for: practical experience.